# ebay style gallery issue

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

So I need help if this is even possible, going to try to be as detailed as possible so you guys understand my problem. I found a simple ebay style gallery code that I want to incorporate into my website i'm making. heres the code

```
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 400px; vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="1_large.jpg" width="398" height="299" alt="Large Photo" style="border: 1px solid #000000;" name="swap">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 6px;"></td>
        <td style="width: 94px; vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="1_small.jpg" width="92" height="69" alt="Small Photo" style="border: 1px solid #000000; margin-bottom: 3px;" onmousedown="document.swap.src='1_large.jpg';">
            <br>
            <img src="2_small.jpg" width="92" height="69" alt="Small Photo" style="border: 1px solid #000000; margin-bottom: 3px;" onmousedown="document.swap.src='2_large.jpg';">
            <br>
            <img src="3_small.jpg" width="92" height="69" alt="Small Photo" style="border: 1px solid #000000; margin-bottom: 3px;" onmousedown="document.swap.src='3_large.jpg';">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I also have a slimbox2 addon into my site, link is here if anyone doesnt know what that is. [slimbox2](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2)
so all i need to do is add this

```
<a href="images/1_large.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src=........./>
```

to allow the image to expand into a larger preview using slimbox, my problem is, if i add it to main image that says "1_large.jpg" the href link is still linked to that specific image, regardless if I "swap" it when i click on another image

for example, i have 3 images in the gallery. the first image is already loaded into the big preview of the ebay style gallery, when  i click on image 3, it gets swapped out to the big preview of the ebay style, now i want to expand it and see the image a lot bigger (this is where slimbox comes in) but once i click the big preview, the image gets expanded, but image 1 gets loaded, not image 3.

hopefully i made the problem clear, if anyone can help that would be fantastic!
all in all, im looking for a photo gallery similar to neweggs website for viewing products

Answer (score 1):

Is this the functionality you're looking for? - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YzXWW/1/)

HTML

```
<div class='bigpic'></div>
<div class='rightbar'>
    <div class='littlepic'><img src='http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130310121325/youtubepoop/images/c/c0/Goofy_Yop.jpg' /></div>
    <div class='littlepic'>
        <img src='http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130706024933/disney/images/8/88/Mickey-Mouse-High-Resolution-Wallpapers.stillmaza.com-1.jpg' /></div>
    <div class='littlepic'><img src='http://images.wikia.com/disney/images/archive/7/71/20121205062928!Donald-duck-disney-photo-450x400-dcp-cpna013154.jpg' /></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bigpic {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bigpic img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
.rightbar {
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.littlepic {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.littlepic img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
$('.littlepic img').on('click', function(){
    $('.bigpic').html('');
    $(this).clone().appendTo('.bigpic');
});
```

---

Edit:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.rightbar .littlepic:first-child img').clone().appendTo('.bigpic');
$('.littlepic img').on('click', function(){
    $('.bigpic').html('');
    $(this).clone().appendTo('.bigpic');
                                           });//end click

});//end ready
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello tim, thank you for the response, im still a little new with adding anything javascript and actually doing anything with it. how and where do i add the javascript portion you put??

Comment: Put it between script tags just above the /body tag at the bottom of your page.

Comment: And don't forget to add the links to jQuery in your header.